# mysql vs ini files?

Tags: php, mysql, configuration, settings

My php program is broken up into modules and each module has its own settings. These settings will hardly change, so would it be better to put the settings in a ini file or in a mysql database?

If I go with the ini style then how hard is it to update the ini file?

Comment: I mean how hard is it to update using php.

Comment: Heres a good comparison of several techniques http://www.phpro.org/articles/Application-Configuration.html Also, you can make your clients a GUI tool to edit ini files using standard html forms. Take a look on Phpclasses.org - there used to be one on there.

Comment: Be sure to consider deployment issues. If you have a configuration file, or a database, do you have one copy at a master configuration server URL? Or does each deployment have a separate configuration. If you use a relational database, where do you store the setting for the settings database?

Comment: SQL configuration stores are inefficient. parse_ini_file() is much faster. If you want to provide a settings UI, try PEAR::Config or Generic PHP Plugins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple text file for configuration has several advantages. Most of all you can use a version control system to compare revisions and to list the history of your configuration files. 
Another advantage is, that you dont need a special tool to write/change configuration settings. Just fire up a text editor (VI that is ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

> If I go with the ini style then how hard is it to update the ini file?

As hard as opening an editor (e.g. two keystrokes: `vi`). You should document your settings properly. Anyway this approach should be preferred over storing configuration settings (even seldom used ones) in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Static site-wide configuration settings are probably best stored in configuration files (INI or XML). User specific configuration settings (ie. user specified theme, language selection) are probably better stored in a database (though you could just as well store these in uniquely named config files).

As for how hard it is to update the ini file : that will depend on the number of settings you store in it. To make this a bit easier on yourself you could create sections per module, so you can jump to the relevant section and quickly change the config vars.

ie.

```
[module1]
var1=value1
var2=value2
...
[module2]
varX=valueX
varY=valueY
...
```

Comment: Can you state why you say so and so?

Answer (score 1):

You could also take out the middle man and have the config stored in a PHP array (no need to parse an INI, or XML, or whatever if that's the case). Really depends on who would end up maintaining the file (developer or non)